# What are the requirements for Once-returner?

Tags: theravada, enlightenment, stages-of-the-path

I know about the ten fetters model. I read that a Once-returner has very reduced desire and aversion to the point that they only appear when tired or unmindful.

Are there other relevant requirements?

Are there stuff that hint that the person is or is not a Once-returner? For example, if the person doesn't reach jhana, does that HINT that maybe he is not a Once-returner?

Comment: Good householder, Bhante Nyanadasanas tables give a good overview in regard of fetters and qualities: [Mental Fetters, etc. Abandoned by Each Path-Knowledge](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/nanadassana/wisdom_en.html#app2), and concentration is sufficent developed starting with No-returner. Others would return. Grave Sensual lust and anger are reduced, compaired to the Streamenter.

Answer (score 2):

The once returner just destroys the 3 fetters and reduce lusts

> Again, Sāriputta, consider the person who is accomplished in the precepts, but not in concentration, nor in wisdom — by destroying the
>   three fetters and reducing lust, hatred and delusion, he becomes a
>   Once-returner, who returns to this world again once only and makes an
>   end of ill.
>
> This, Sāvatthi, is the sixth person, who, dying with some attached
>   remainder, is altogether freed from hell, rebirth in the womb of an
>   animal, the realm of ghosts, from the untoward way, the ill way, the
>   abyss, hell.

http://obo.genaud.net/dhamma-vinaya/pts/an/09_nines/an09.012.hare.pts.htm#p1

Apparently the first people who are ''moderately'' good at concentration are the ''Clan-to-clan-goer''